# Work with my passion or move on?

Tags: software-industry, resignation

Since this year, the company that I work at has started integrating with a big corporate IT company that acquired it a couple years ago. The integration has brought a lot of changes and has changed culture to one that is very different from the old one. Due to this, quite a few people have already left our company. until now, this did not bother me as long as I could do my thing as a programmer.

Due to people leaving and the acquisition, a lot of work and business activities have shifted to our head office. This has lead to a lot of my colleagues working at the head office for a couple days a week. This change has become a problem since some more people left last week, but a whole team has also been moved to a different location for multiple days a week. So now I sometimes spend my days alone in the office and this is really demotivating.

The head office is 1.5 hours away from where I currently work. I don't have any work reason to go to the head office, because I'm the only person in my company with experience in the technology that I work with. I mainly work on projects by myself, but I do really enjoy having colleagues around even though I do not directly work with them. **Going to the head office just to talk to people isn't worth it for me due to the travel time and medical reasons.**

Besides having my colleagues around, I also struggle with the amount of work. The technology that I work with is new and a niche, so currently there aren't many other companies who work with this, but it really is my passion and it has given me a lot of growth within the company. I'm about to be planned for a project next month, but I really don't want to spend most of that time alone in the office and once I'm on the project I feel I can't quit. (It's a project that runs for multiple months). So I'm currently torn between doing what I like in a demotivating office for a couple months and trying to find something else.

One option would be to quit now, but I'm not sure if I would find something new before that and I know it's not smart to quit before having signed something new. It also does not help that my lead isn't available for a couple weeks due to their holidays, so before I can talk to them, I might already be on the project.

Does anyone have any pointers? Should I just sit out the ride until I find something, even when this means being really demotivated or just quit and figure out what to do from there?

Comment: Is'nt there a way for you to communicate with your colleagues without having to go the main office ?

Comment: Work from home?

Comment: Yeah I did think about working from home and communicate with everyone through chat, but I enjoy having people around and the 5 minute chats at the coffee machine in the morning. So I do not think that is for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have cited two problems here :

1. You are demotivated by being alone in the office
2. Struggling with the amount of work

One solution would be to solve those two problems at once, by telling your management that you are struggling with the amount of work you have, and need helping hands. If you're willing you could volunteer to train to the technology you are currently using, so that they don't have to seek out experts on that specific technology.

If that's not possible, I would advise to polish up your CV, and find something else. Do not worry about quitting mid project, as long as you give your notice, and respect your contract when leaving, replacing you is the responsibility of your employer, not yours.

Answer (score 1):

How do you evaluate your chances to get another job that you will appreciate ? Also does your country offer unemployment compensation ? If so you could leave without being in trouble and find another job.

As you really don't enjoy being alone in the office and that is not going to change as I got it, I'd probably move on if I were you.